# C: Bit-wise operations and bit padding

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

**EDIT: The premise was faulty and thanks to other users' comments, I realize the system I described below cannot work.** But I wonder, is there a system that *would* work for storing flags in different positions within a variable so that it can be simultaneously used to store either a high-precision small value or a lower-precision large value?

**Original question:**

In C11 and C++11, I want to stuff two single-bit flags into a `size_t` variable that I am simultaneously using to store an unrelated value. Since that value will usually be low, my idea is to use the two *most significant* bits to store the flags *unless* the third-most significant bit is set, in which case I store the flags in the two *least significant* bits. That way, if the value is within the usual range, it can have a precision of one, and if the value is huge, it can have a precision of four. I can figure out where the flags are stored and how to interpret the value just by checking the third-most significant bit.

Unlike the `uintN_t` types, the standards don't seem to guarantee that size_t has no padding bits. I’m not well-versed in bit-twiddling. In the unlikely event of a system that uses padding bits in `size_t`, will the bit-wise operations I need to implement this system result in undefined behavior?

To satisfy the curious, I don't want to store the flags in a separate `char` because memory usage is a priority and doing so would enlarge the containing struct by `max_align_t` on most systems (because of struct alignment/padding).

Comment: Can you explain why you think the presence of any "padding bits" would make any difference at all, to the overall task at hand? If you know that you need to set bit #n, and there are some "padding bits" somewhere, what difference do you think that might have, on the task at hand, of setting bit #n?

Comment: Have you thought this through? Consider a 16-bit `size_t`. The values 0x0000 through 0x1fff have the third-most-significant bit clear. Then 0x2000-0x3fff have it set, although you would only be using the multiples of four, 0x2000-0x3ffc. Fine so far. Then 0x4000 has that bit clear again, so it would represent 0 with the extra bits of 0 and 1. So it is not useful for a high value. The next bit string with the third-MSB set is 0x6000. Is it going to represent the value 0x4000, since that is the next after the 0x3ffc from before? Are you prepared to do the arithmetic/bit twiddling to manage that?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The reason - I suppose - is my unfamiliarity with bit operations. Getting bits at the least-significant end seems trivial. But if I use `my_variable >> ( sizeof( size_t ) * 8 - 1 ) & 1` and size_t has padding at the most-significant end, then aren't I tapping into the padding bits because sizeof returns the _size_, not the _width_, of the type?

Comment: @EricPostpischil "Have you thought this through?" -> Evidently not! I was thinking about the fact that for every value < SIZE_MAX / 2, the most significant bit would be clear, and that for every value > SIZE_MAX / 2, it would be set, and then extrapolating that idea to the next most significant bits. But as you pointed out, that premise is totally faulty and I'm in over my head.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Now that you've pointed out the gross problem with my idea, I wonder, is there a system that _would_ work for storing flags in different positions within a variable so that it can be simultaneously used to store either a high-precision small value or a lower-precision large value?

Comment: "Simultaneously used to store either a high-precision small value or a lower-precision large value?" Like floating-point?

Answer (score 0):

> In the unlikely event of a system that uses padding bits in `size_t`,
> will the bit-wise operations I need to implement this system result in
> undefined behavior?

I infer that your concern is that you might inadvertently try to twiddle a padding bit.  You do not need to worry about that, because the bitwise operations are defined in terms of values, not the details of the representations of those values.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was wondering about, although as one of the commentators pointed out, the system I was describing made no sense to begin with :S